# X and kwin_wayland running at the same time

Tags: xorg, kde, wayland

I'm running KDE on Ubuntu with a NVidia graphics card. The command `nvidia-smi` gives the following output:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
... elided ...
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2098      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           50MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3425      G   /usr/bin/kwin_wayland                       486MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it normal or harmful that both Xorg and kwin_wayland are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

Yes, is normal and not harmful

## Medium Answer

There can be cases when KDE runs both Xorg and kwin_wayland simultaneously. Keep in mind they do different things:

- **Xorg**: This component provides compatibility for running X11 applications on the Wayland display server.
- **kwin_wayland**: This is the Wayland compositor for the KDE Plasma desktop environment. It manages the graphical user interface, handles window management, and is responsible for the overall display in a Wayland session.

## Long Answer

### Xorg

[Windowing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system) that interacts with client applications through the X11 protocol. The X system became pretty soon the default windowing system.

When a client connects and sends inputs like mouse movements or keyboard press Xorg draws on the window display.

It has few years on it's back and still some little problems. But still...it work !

### Kwin_Wayland

KWin is a [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) for the X Window System and a Wayland compositor. It can also be used on its own or with other desktop environments.

Some people advice (in case you want to use kwin_wayland) to just use the Wayland session.

### Ending

So, "windowing system" and "window manager" refer to different components of a graphical user interface (GUI) system. They can work together to provide the visual elements and user interactions in a graphical environment.

Comment: Google didn't give me anything useful, ChatGPT claims it's bad. What am I missing?

Comment: Honest...don't know what to tell. you got my curiosity about ChatGPT and he gave me more or less the reply i gave you. Wait. im gonna upload the screenshot somewhere - UPDATED: https://i.imgur.com/LZWh1UG.png

Comment: And my bad..by google i should have specified key words and the fact that i landed on reddit

Comment: if all your ultimate solution is saying for people to "Google It" then your post is not an answer nor allowed.  Just making sure you are aware of what makes a good answer or not.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard for the feedback. I will update my answer tonight :)